# How to get linq sum of IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

How do I get the sum of numbers that are in an IEnumerable collection of objects?  I know for sure that the underlying type will always be numeric but the type is determined at runtime.

```
IEnumerable<object> listValues = data.Select(i => Convert.ChangeType(property.GetValue(i, null), columnType));
```

After that I want to be able to do the following (the following has the error:"Cannot resolve method Sum"):

```
var total = listValues.Sum();
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Why is the exact type determined at runtime? That sounds very fishy!

Comment: If the type is determined at runtime, that sounds like a job for Generics.  Do you have access to the creation of the `IEnumerable<object> listValues`?  Could you change it to `IEnumerable<T> where T : struct, IConvertible`?

Comment: @Tory - yes I have access to the creation of the IEnumerable but I don't know exactly how to make the change you are suggesting.  I'm new to the Generics world, please provide an example, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use expression trees to generate the required add function, then fold over your input list:

```
private static Func<object, object, object> GenAddFunc(Type elementType)
{
    var param1Expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var param2Expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var addExpr = Expression.Add(Expression.Convert(param1Expr, elementType), Expression.Convert(param2Expr, elementType));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object, object>>(Expression.Convert(addExpr, typeof(object)), param1Expr, param2Expr).Compile();
}

IEnumerable<object> listValues;
Type elementType = listValues.First().GetType();
var addFunc = GenAddFunc(elementType);

object sum = listValues.Aggregate(addFunc);
```

note this requires the input list to be non-empty, but it has the advantage of preserving the element type in the result.

Comment: your solution works perfectly fine! just trying to understand the whole concept. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

If you know the exact type is always going to be a numeric type, you should be able to use something like:

```
double total = listValues.Sum(v => Convert.ToDouble(v));
```

This will work because `Convert.ToDouble` will look for [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx), which is implemented by the core numeric types.  You are forcing the type to be a `double` and not the original type, as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is might throw an `InvalidCastException` for e.g. strings and other objects!

Comment: @ebeeb - that is true, the code before that call ensures that only numeric types are getting to that point.

Comment: Reed - your solution is simple and works just fine, but I would like to preserve the original type.

Comment: @Mike the problem is there's no way to specify the compile time type to even set the variable properly.  You could (potentially) put it in an `object`, but that won't be very useful...

Answer (score 0):

convert to one type. Say, decimal.

> data.Select(i => Convert.ToDecimal(property.GetValue(i, null)).Sum();

Answer (score -1):

you can use dyanmic, works perfect:

```
    listValues.Sum(x => (dynamic)x);
```

Comment: In my scenario this solution only works when the underlying type is int.